# When would I need to use ng-template?

Tags: angularjs, templates

I've been trying to get my head around `ng-template` and where and when I may need it. After looking at a few tutorials I am still none the wiser.

If I have defined a template eg.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-template-id">
    ... html here
</script>
```

I have seen that sometimes this is used with `ng-include` and sometimes as a templateUrl in a directive.

Also once I read that it goes in to the `$templateCache`, what benefit do I get from using this? I am using Angular to dynamically list products, no great shakes there but if I can get more performance from using something like `ng-template` I would like to have a go at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script types `ng-template` are used to embed html fragments inline. These fragments can then be used by `ng-include` or directives to load the html fragment and construct the view.

Advantage of inline template fragments is that there is one less call to make to server to load the html template which is required in standard scenario. Not  a huge advantage considering the template is cached for future use.

The disadvantage could be that you may never use the inline template at all and it just gets loaded as part of parent view content.