# Which assets are downloaded on device when hybrid app is downloaded from app store?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am super curios, spent several hour on internet but all I can find are "pros&cons for html5, hybrid and native app" sytle blogs.

One if reasons why mobile app performs faster then web app (aside from fact that app can use device core functionality) is that assets are stored in device memory thus dont have to be fetched over internet, only information(JSON) travels over internet. This reduces the load time, reduces time to load new page(you only need to get JSON) and adds offline experience.

I has kind of living in world where hybrid app does the same - assets are stored in device. However in ionic documentation I found this:

> The good thing about Angular templates is they can be loaded from
>   anywhere: locally or remote. The URL of the template is the unique
>   identifier, and if the template is defined locally, it will be fetched
>   locally. Templates are a great way to separate layouts and UIs, so we
>   use them extensively.

This suggests that if template is not defined locally it will not be fetched locally leaving me with assumption that template that is defined in my www folder will be called over internet.

Also I found a place in their docs(realy couldnt find exact words to qoute) where they suggested to define template inside script tags because otherwise they would be fetched over internet.

This leaves me wondering which files are actually downloaded on my device when I download app from app store or google play?

I find this very important to understand this before actually start developing hybrid apps with any framework and as I could not find any information on this subject I hope that this question will be relevant to other developers who are taking first step into hybrid app development.

Answer (score 0):

In short, your whole `www` folder is downloaded onto the device, whether the files in there are used or not. That whole folder is always copied into the application and downloaded by the user. In addition, there are a lot of Cordova related things included in the app, things like plugins.

The easiest way to see what will be bundled in your app is to build one for iOS or Android and open it in Android Studio or Xcode and see what is in there, it should give you a good overview of what the user gets.

---

> This suggests that if template is not defined locally it will not be
>   fetched locally leaving me with assumption that template that is
>   defined in my www folder will be called over internet.

I am not entirely sure what you mean with this sentence. If a template is not defined in your app, then loading it over the internet would be an option, but why wouldn't it be defined? If a template is defined in your `www` folder, how can it be not defined in your app?

---

So you linked to [an article](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-tutorial-2-anathomy-of-a-page/) that describes different approaches to defining templates in Ionic and Angular. The difference between loading a template and defining it using `ng-template` has to do with the fact that you can include multiple `ng-template` inside the same HTML file, which means that you do not need to load any templates from other files. Basically, if you load a file and there are multiple `ng-template` in there, they will be cached as soon as the file is loaded and this may increase performance. I was not able to find convincing evidence regarding the differences between the two approaches, it seems to be relatively small. These two questions also answer similar question, you can find them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038304/when-would-i-need-to-use-ng-template) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453024/are-there-any-benefits-of-pre-fetching-templates-in-angularjs).

Comment: The author of the article is pointing at the fact that loading a template is going to take slightly longer than loading a `ng-template`, which is usually included in the same HTML file. I have expanded my answer to elaborate the difference.